# Does only marriage relationship cause a Green Card?

Tags: usa, greencard, family, marriage

Do other types of relationship like partnership also make someone eligible for Green Card or it's just for legal marriage

I am a F-1 student in the US and like to know which kind of relationships will makes someone eligible for Green Card?

Comment: By "relationship", do you only mean family relationships? Or do employment relationships also count?

Comment: @user102008: I mean relationships like marriage, partnership, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The only family relationships that can lead to a green card are:

- Spouse
- Son or daughter
- Parent
- Brother or sister

If the sponsor is a green card holder rather than a US citizen, then the relationships are further limited to

- Spouse
- Unmarried son or daughter

Source: [US Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/family-immigration.html)

"Spouse" means "husband or wife"; civil partnerships are not included.

There are also green cards available for various employment relationships, but it seems that these are beyond the scope of your question.